# How to run a .sh in different nodes using different data in slurm?

Tags: parallel-processing, cluster-computing, slurm, hpc

I'm a beginner in Slurm and  I would like some help with the following problem. I've made a .sh, within which, initially, a matlab script creates two arrays (based on the value of a parameter i). Then, those arrays are being used by a Fortran program that computes a number of other arrays.

I want this process to be performed at the same time for 10 different values of i (in 10 different nodes(?)).

```
`I have the following slurm script but I'm pretty sure I'm doing it wrong.

#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --job-name=Name
#SBATCH --nodes=10
#SBATCH --ntasks=10
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=1


for i in {1..10}
do
 srun -n1 --exclusive ./gaia.sh $i &
done
date`
```

I'm getting a message Warning: "can't run 1 processes on 10 nodes, setting nnodes to 1" .

Can someone provide some help?

Answer (score 1):

To get rid of the warning, add `--nodes=1` in addition to the current parameters in line

```
srun -n1 --exclusive ./gaia.sh $i &
```

That said, there is probably no reason to force Slurm to use 10 different nodes. You could remove all the references to `--nodes=...`.

If, furthermore, there is no real requirement for all runs of the `./gaia.sh` script to run concurrently, you can simply use a [job array](https://slurm.schedmd.com/job_array.html):

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --job-name=Name
#SBATCH --array=1-10
#SBATCH --ntasks=1


./gaia.sh $SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID  


date
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @damienfrancois! Actually, you 're right there's no dependance between runs. Thing is though, I need that i variable to change value among the runs (1 to 10). In the code you provided i is obviously $SLURM_TASK_ARRAY_ID but its value doesn't change, it remains 1 for each one of the 10 runs. Perhaps there's something I get wrong?

Comment: My bad, I wrote `$SLURM_TASK_ARRAY_ID` instead of `$SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID`, a mistake I often do. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I just figured it out myself and was writing an answer :) Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Allow me another question on the above script..I'm not sure I fully understand how ntasks works in a job-array.  I have 10 identical "tasks" that need to be implemented here and I consider that one task (--ntasks=1) in a size 10 array? Why not a --ntasks=10 in a size 10 array? Thanks again for your kind help :)

Comment: `--ntasks=1 --array=1-10` leads to 10 times a 1-task job, while `--ntasks=10 --array=1-10`leads to 10 times a 10-tasks job.